# How do I export powerpoint slide notes to individual text files?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Through some research, I came across this VBA code on the following site:
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00481_Export_the_notes_text_of_a_presentation.htm

```
Sub ExportNotesText()

Dim oSlides As Slides
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim strNotesText As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim intFileNum As Integer
Dim lngReturn As Long

' Get a filename to store the collected text
strFileName = InputBox("Enter the full path and name of file to extract notes text to", "Output file?")

' did user cancel?
If strFileName = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

' is the path valid?  crude but effective test:  try to create the file.
intFileNum = FreeFile()
On Error Resume Next
Open strFileName For Output As intFileNum
If Err.Number <> 0 Then     ' we have a problem
    MsgBox "Couldn't create the file: " & strFileName & vbCrLf _
        & "Please try again."
    Exit Sub
End If
Close #intFileNum  ' temporarily

' Get the notes text
Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oSl In oSlides
    For Each oSh In oSl.NotesPage.Shapes
    If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
        If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
            If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                strNotesText = strNotesText & "Slide: " & CStr(oSl.SlideIndex) & vbCrLf _
                & oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Next oSh
Next oSl

' now write the text to file
Open strFileName For Output As intFileNum
Print #intFileNum, strNotesText
Close #intFileNum

' show what we've done
lngReturn = Shell("NOTEPAD.EXE " & strFileName, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

It essentially exports ALL the slide notes from a Powerpoint file into ONE text file in chronological order of slides.

Is there anyway to alter the code to output the slide notes into multiple text files? What I mean is, if there are 4 slides in the powerpoint document, we would get an export of each slide's notes as follows:

- slide1notes.txt
- slide2notes.txt
- slide3notes.txt
- slide4notes.txt

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have a great deal of time to do more than aircode this, but:

```
Sub TryThis()
' Write each slide's notes to a text file
' in same directory as presentation itself
' Each file is named NNNN_Notes_Slide_xxx
' where NNNN is the name of the presentation
'       xxx is the slide number

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strNotesText As String
Dim intFileNum As Integer

' Get the notes text
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.NotesPage.Shapes
        If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
            If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
                If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    ' now write the text to file
                    strFileName = ActivePresentation.Path _
                        & "\" & ActivePresentation.Name & "_Notes_" _
                        & "Slide_" & CStr(oSl.SlideIndex) _
                        & ".TXT"
                    intFileNum = FreeFile()
                    Open strFileName For Output As intFileNum
                    Print #intFileNum, oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                    Close #intFileNum
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next oSh
Next oSl

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you steve....unfortunately, it didn't quite work. Getting an error that says:  "Run-time error'-2147483640 (80000008)': PlaceholderFormat (unknown member) : Failed."

Comment: pressing "Debug" highlights this line:  If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then

Comment: I've corrected one error in the code .. added intFileNum = FreeFile() ... but otherwise it works fine here.  What version of PowerPoint are you running this in?  That might account for the error you're seeing.

Comment: I'm running the latest Powerpoint 2011 on a Mac, and still getting the same error.  Perhaps explain what I'm doing: Open PPT file > Tools > Macro > Visual Basic Editor > Insert > Module > paste your code in the new window > Run > Error message above.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" Using Mac PowerPoint.  ;-)  I can repro the problem here. It appears to be a bug in the Mac implementation; a bit more testing shows that it fails when it gets to the slide number placeholder on the notes page.  So add On Error Resume Next at the top then before grabbing the text, make sure Err.Number = 0

Comment: And since this is on a mac, you'll need to edit the paths to the output text file; left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

And since Mac PPT/VBA is bug-infested, here's a new version for Mac.  Since I'm doing this on a PC and can't copy/paste to/from the Mac, I haven't run the code on Mac, but it should be ok:

```
Sub TryThis()
' Write each slide's notes to a text file
' in same directory as presentation itself
' Each file is named NNNN_Notes_Slide_xxx
' where NNNN is the name of the presentation
'       xxx is the slide number

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strNotesText As String
Dim intFileNum As Integer

' Since Mac PPT will toss non-fatal errors, just keep moving along:
On Error Resume Next

' Get the notes text
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.NotesPage.Shapes

        ' Here's where the error will occur, if any:
        If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
        ' so deal with it if so:
        If Err.Number = 0 Then 
            If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
                If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    ' now write the text to file
                    strFileName = ActivePresentation.Path _
                        & "\" & ActivePresentation.Name & "_Notes_" _
                        & "Slide_" & CStr(oSl.SlideIndex) _
                        & ".TXT"
                    intFileNum = FreeFile()
                    Open strFileName For Output As intFileNum
                    Print #intFileNum, oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                    Close #intFileNum
                End If  ' HasText
            End If   ' HasTextFrame
        End If  ' Err.Number = 0
        End If  ' PlaceholderType test
    Next oSh
Next oSl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs the output in one txt-file:

```
Sub TryThis()
' Write each slide's notes to a text file
' in same directory as presentation itself
' Each file is named NNNN_Notes_Slide_xxx
' where NNNN is the name of the presentation
'       xxx is the slide number

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strNotesText As String
Dim intFileNum As Integer
Dim strLine As String
Dim strData As String

' Since Mac PPT will toss non-fatal errors, just keep moving along:
On Error Resume Next

' Get the notes text
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.NotesPage.Shapes

        ' Here's where the error will occur, if any:
        If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
        ' so deal with it if so:
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
                If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    strData = strData + "Folie " & oSl.SlideIndex & vbCrLf & oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    Close #intFileNum
                End If  ' HasText
            End If   ' HasTextFrame
        End If  ' Err.Number = 0
        End If  ' PlaceholderType test
    Next oSh
Next oSl

' now write the text to file
strFileName = ActivePresentation.Path _
& "\" & ActivePresentation.Name & "_Notes" _
& ".txt"
intFileNum = FreeFile()
Open strFileName For Output As intFileNum
Print #intFileNum, strData
Close #intFileNum

End Sub
```