# Add text to VBA exported text file using TextRange.InsertAfter method

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to export notes to text files from a PowerPoint using [this VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881795/3990276). In each exported text file I want to add an extra piece of text at the end of the text within the file that is exported. Its seems this is possible with the [TextRange.InsertAfter method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.insertafter) but I am not sure how to do it.

Let say the text that I want to add at the end of each text range in file is "extra text", I thought something like this might work

Orignal

```
Print #intFileNum, oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

Revised

```
Print #intFileNum, oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter "extra text".Text
```

Alas not..

This is the VBA

```
Sub TryThis()
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strNotesText As String
Dim intFileNum As Integer

' Get the notes text
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.NotesPage.Shapes
        If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
            If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
                If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    ' now write the text to file
                    strFileName = ActivePresentation.Path _
                        & "\" & ActivePresentation.Name & "_Notes_" _
                        & "Slide_" & CStr(oSl.SlideIndex) _
                        & ".TXT"
                    intFileNum = FreeFile()
                    Open strFileName For Output As intFileNum
                    Print #intFileNum, oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter "extra text".Text
                    Close #intFileNum
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next oSh
Next oSl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I worked it out. This adds the text to each slide, exports to TXT and then deletes the text from the slide

```
oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter "extra text"
Print #intFileNum, oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace FindWhat:="extra text", ReplaceWhat:=""
```